# ctx.font only changes img width and not the fontsize - Html canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I tried adding a Download feature to my website bit when i try changing the font size it only changes the width of the img and not the font. so with a fontsize of 30px the img has almost 3x the size. but the font didnt change.

```
      function downloadImage() {
         // Get the quote and name from the HTML elements
         var quote = document.getElementById("zitat").innerText;
         var name = document.getElementById("Name").innerText;
       
         // Create a canvas element
         var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
       
         // Set the canvas size to fit the text
         var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
         ctx.font = "30px Arial";
         var quoteWidth = ctx.measureText(quote).width;
         var nameWidth = ctx.measureText("- " + name).width;
         canvas.width = Math.max(quoteWidth) + 20;
         canvas.height = 80;
       
         // Draw the quote and name on the canvas
         ctx.fillStyle = "#ff9329";
         ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
         ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
         ctx.fillText("Zitat Shuffle", canvas.width / 2 - nameWidth / 2 , 20);
         ctx.fillText(quote, 20, 40);
         ctx.fillText(name, canvas.width / 2 - nameWidth / 2 , 70);
         ctx.font = "30px Arial";
         // Convert the canvas to a data URL
         var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
       
         // Create a link element and click it to download the image
         var link = document.createElement("a");
         link.download = "qoute.png";
         link.href = dataURL;
         link.click();
       
         // Remove the canvas element from the document
         canvas.remove();
       }
       

       function shareImage() {
         // Get the data URL of the canvas image
         var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
         var blob = dataURLToBlob(dataURL);
         
         // Create a modal dialog box
         var popup = document.createElement("div");
         popup.classList.add("popup");
       
         // Create a container for the dialog box content
         var popupContent = document.createElement("div");
         popupContent.classList.add("popup-content");
       
         // Create a close button for the modal dialog box
         var closeBtn = document.createElement("span");
         closeBtn.classList.add("close");
         closeBtn.innerHTML = "&times;";
         closeBtn.onclick = function() {
            popup.style.display = "none";
         };
       
         // Create a button to copy the image to the clipboard
         var copyBtn = document.createElement("button");
         copyBtn.type = "button";
         copyBtn.innerHTML = "Copy to clipboard";
         copyBtn.onclick = function() {
           navigator.clipboard.write([new ClipboardItem({ 'image/png': blob })])
             .then(function() {
               alert("Image copied to clipboard!");
             })
             .catch(function() {
               alert("Failed to copy image to clipboard");
             });
         };
       
         // Create placeholders for sharing options
         var InstagramBtn = document.createElement("button");
         InstagramBtn.innerHTML = "Share on Instagram";
         InstagramBtn.classList.add("share-button");
         InstagramBtn.classList.add("instagram");
       
         var twitterBtn = document.createElement("button");
         twitterBtn.innerHTML = "Share on Twitter";
         twitterBtn.classList.add("share-button");
         twitterBtn.classList.add("twitter");
       
         var redditBtn = document.createElement("button");
         redditBtn.innerHTML = "Share by Reddit";
         redditBtn.classList.add("share-button");
         redditBtn.classList.add("reddit");
       
         // Add the dialog box content to the popup dialog box
         popupContent.appendChild(closeBtn);
         popupContent.appendChild(copyBtn);
         popupContent.appendChild(InstagramBtn);
         popupContent.appendChild(twitterBtn);
         popupContent.appendChild(redditBtn);
         popup.appendChild(popupContent);
       
         // Add the popup dialog box to the document body
         document.body.appendChild(popup);
       
         // Show the popup dialog box
         popup.style.display = "block";
       }
       
       function dataURLToBlob(dataURL) {
         var arr = dataURL.split(",");
         var mime = arr[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1];
         var bstr = atob(arr[1]);
         var n = bstr.length;
         var u8arr = new Uint8Array(n);
         while (n--) {
           u8arr[n] = bstr.charCodeAt(n);
         }
         return new Blob([u8arr], {type:mime});
       }
```

I tried finding anybody online with the same problem and didnt find anything.

Comment: You need to set again the `font` property after you changed the bitmap's size.

Comment: sadly it didnt work.
but still thank you

Comment: You need to set it before you call `ctx.fillText()`. Set it right after `canvas.height = 80;`